# Using Entity Framework from Model automatically created from database

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I'm trying to start using Entity Framework. I'm first trying to fill a log (type, message, date) table.

My procedure:

1. Create table
2. Add ADO.NET Entity Data Model
3. Generate model from database
4. ?

I don't know how to use the model to actually access the database.

I tried to find tutorials but all of them left important parts without details. If someone could elaborate on an explanation or provide a tutorial which is good and *complete*, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: If you're starting from scratch, why not use Code First? It's a less clunky workflow if you don't need to support a legacy database.

Comment: I don't know what step #4 is either, but step #5 is "PROFIT".

Comment: "I tried to find tutorials but all of them left important parts without details" - this sounds false to me. Start with the official tutorials, and come back to ask about said details. SO is not the place to ask for walkthroughs through whole technology stacks.

Comment: I mean, just the one that's a side-track from the ASP.NET MVC one is an exhausting ten-parter: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [pluralsight.com](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=efarchitecture&highlight=julie-lerman_efarchitecture-m2-boundedcontext%2a4!julie-lerman_efarchitecture-m4-testing%2a4#efarchitecture-m2-boundedcontext), sign up for the free trial and do the course Entity Framework in the Enterprise.

Comment: PluralSight is awesome! Try to check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907 out as well. They provide a bunch of straightforward tutorial on EF. To be specific, when you go the site, CTRL-F and look for "Using EF With Other Technologies".

Answer (score 0):

It exposes a class called {YourModelName}Entities

```
var myContext = new BlahBlahEntities(yourConnectionString);
```

Your tables are properties on this object.  The objects representing your tables are also exposed in the same namespace the the {...}Entites.  You can add and remove items from the table properties on the context, and then call SaveChanges() to actually apply the changes to the database (until SaveChanges are called, changes only exist on the copy of Entities that youare using).